# adding Scrollbar listener to JOGL project

Tags: java, event-handling, jogl

As the title suggests I am trying to add an event listener to a [JOGL](http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/pages/Home) project to no avail. Any
help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used JOGL, but from the link it looks like its a 3D painting API. If so then the general rule for custom paiting is that you need to specify the preferred size of the panel where you are doing the custom painting. This is because scrollbars only appear when the preferred size of the panel is greater than the size of the scrollpane. Once the scrollbars appear your listener should work.

Comment: that is the thing, I already have a scrollbar added to the window 
but for some reason I can't add a event listener to it, tried following the method used for keyboard event listener to no avail